# Printing multiple messages in Android software

Tags: android

I have been searching other stackoverflow questions and also looking through the android developer guide but I have not found an solution yet.. In my program I ask the user to enter in a homework assignment that they have just received. From there I take that message and I print it on a new screen. What I want to be able to do is save the previous messages entered in and print those out each time along with the new message. What I am having trouble is printing more than one message at a time. I used setContentView but it only prints one message. Does anyone have any advice? I have posted my code at the bottom:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

 // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    saveHomework(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);


}

public void saveHomework(String message)
{
    String message2 = message;

    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView2.setTextSize(40);
    textView2.setText(message2);

    setContentView(textView2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently you should preserve all previously entered messages in some place.

Your options:

1. If you are sure your activity process is alive all the time user can enter the messages, you can use some static variable of the activity and store there the messages in a list or array.
2. If your process can be closed you should store the messages in a filed using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Then, whereever you want to show the messages you should read them from where you have them saved and pass all together to setText(messages_list) call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using an array list but I am a little confused about how setText could help. While checking the Android Database I didn't see anything about setText being able to print out strings to the android activity

Comment: But you've already done that... Because textView2.setText(messages_list) "Sets the text that this TextView is to display". What was wrong ?